# SemanticZoom: is it possible to stop the view transition in code behind?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a grouped gridview inside my "zoomed in" part of the semanticView control. Groups can be empty (I used ).
In my "zoomed out" gridview I have listed all letters from "A" to "Z". Letters referring to empty groups appears disabled (dimmed Foreground, there isn't a "IsEnabled" property available here).
What I need to do is abort the "zoom in" transition in response to a click on a letter corresponding to an empty Group.
Any suggestion?
Thanks for your time.

Orf Quarenghi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of this answer as I currently have no way to check/test - but as a suggestion I would check if IsEnabled property disables the semantic zoom transition from firing.

You mentioned there isn't an 'IsEnabled' property - what are you checking? If you use a datatemplate to render your UI in the gridview you could use something like a Border (which does have IsEnabled) to wrap your Child/Item UI and bind the 'IsEnabled' property to the respective field on whatever you have placed in your ItemSource.

Comment: Border doesn't have the IsEnabled property - nor any other controls container have, like Grid or StackPanel. That would've been too good to be true :o/

Comment: Perhaps try wrapping the content in a <Button> </Button> and overriding the default button style? It has IsEnabled